# doubleValue from NSString, decimals get removed

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsnumberformatter

Here I am using `NSNumberFormater` to set max number of decimals in a double to two. It seems to work fine, but when I try to convert it back to a double, from the string generated by `NSNumberFormater`, as you can see in the `NSLog` output, any decimal is removed and replaced by trailing zeros. Why is this?

```
- (double)randomDoubleBetween:(double)smallNumber and:(double)bigNumber {
    double diff = bigNumber - smallNumber;
    double ranNum = (((double) (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1)) / RAND_MAX) * diff) + smallNumber;

    NSNumberFormatter *doubleValueWithMaxDecimalDigits = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [doubleValueWithMaxDecimalDigits setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [doubleValueWithMaxDecimalDigits setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:ranNum];

    NSString *valueToReturn = [doubleValueWithMaxDecimalDigits stringFromNumber:num];
    NSLog(@"String value %@", valueToReturn);

    NSLog(@"Double value converted from string %f", [valueToReturn doubleValue]);
    return [valueToReturn doubleValue];
}
```

NSLog output:

> 2013-08-09 02:25:05.031 GG[27947:907] String value 176,19
>
> 2013-08-09 02:25:05.035 GG[27947:907] Double value converted from string 176.000000

Comment: Why are you formatting that in the first place?

Comment: @Josh: I need to limit the number of decimals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `-[NSString doubleValue]` isn't respecting the locale decimal separator; it expects a point, not a comma.

```
// US uses point as decimal separator
[doubleValueWithMaxDecimalDigits setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

NSString *valueToReturn = [doubleValueWithMaxDecimalDigits stringFromNumber:num];

// Correctly includes fractional part
NSLog(@"Double value converted from string %lf", [valueToReturn doubleValue]);

// Italy uses a comma
[doubleValueWithMaxDecimalDigits setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"it_IT"]];
valueToReturn = [doubleValueWithMaxDecimalDigits stringFromNumber:num];

// Drops fractional part
NSLog(@"Double value converted from string %lf", [valueToReturn doubleValue]);
```

I'm not sure why you're formatting the number into a string that you don't use, but if you're going to continue to do that, use the same formatter again to parse the string into a `double` before returning.

(Aside, your format specifier is wrong; use `%lf` for `double`.)

Comment: Formating to a string seems to be the only way of limiting the number of decimals. What you said about comma! I just noticed that.